# What is a symmetry defect?

Tags: field-theory, definition, symmetry-breaking, topological-field-theory, topological-defects

I found that it is a normal concept appearing in condensed matter physics and especially topological order field. I have been aware of the topological defect. But what is a symmetry defect? Could someone explain or give a simple concrete example?

Answer (score 0):

A symmetry defect of a topologically ordered system with a symmetry $G$ is an extrinsic defect that "carries" a nontrivial group element $g \in G$ [1]. This means that anyons are acted upon $g$ after being taken around the symmetry defect.

In Sec. 5 of Ref. [1], a way of introducing such a symmetry defect in a topologically ordered system is explained with a simple lattice model.

[1] M. Barkeshli, P. Bonderson, M. Cheng, Z. Wang, *Phys. Rev. B* **100**, 115147 (2019).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can not comprehend these papers completely. But just for the notion of symmetry defect, I think this is a stuff transforming differently from other parts which transform uniformly  under a specific group. Is this description or picture correct?

Comment: Well, I think you cannot think symmetry defect in that way; anyons actually transform differently from other parts under global symmetry action, but I don't think people consider anyons as symmetry defects. Anyons are "intrinsic defects" rather than extrinsic. Maybe the most familiar example of symmetry defect is magnetic flux, which induces U(1) Aharanov-Bohm phase to an anyon when it comes around a loop encircling the flux. This is the global U(1) action on anyon.